# Passing a null or empty string to a @Html.TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a form that I want the user to complete. It is associated to a quote that is already partly populated based on some previous behaviors. On the model I have some additional properties that I want to capture when the user comes to order. The problem I am having is that when I create the initial quote with some of the values, the remaining values are set to null. This causes a problem when I then try and collect the rest of the values using:

```
@Html.TextBox(quote.CompanyName)
```

but it returns an error that the Value cannot be null or empty.

Is it not possible to get en input for the other values I want to store using this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accually the argument you pass to [`TextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492494%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) is a `name` of your input, so it cannot be null, you can use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492984%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) overload if you want to set `value`:

```
@Html.TextBox("CompanyName", "MyValue")
```

which will produce:

```
<input type="text" name="CompanyName" value="MyValue" />
```

Comment: thank you. I have been banging my head against the table for some time on this now. Cheers